# On the addition of elements in Cantor Set

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $C$ denote the standard Cantor set. It is well known that $C+C=[0,2]$. (Here, by $C+C$ we simply mean what it should be naturally: the set $\{x+y\colon x,y\in C\}$.

**Question 1.** For some $a$ in the Cantor set, if $a+a$ is also in the Cantor set, then is it necessary that $a=0$?

**Question 2.** Every element of $[0,2]$ can be written as addition of two elements of the Cantor set. What can we about uniqueness of such representation?

The partial answer to Question 2 is the following: some elements of $[0,2]$ have not a unique representation: for example, $1=0+1$ and $1=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}$. Also, $\frac{2}{3}$ can be written as $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}$ and $0+\frac{2}{3}$.

I want to see whether there are any other such elements with non-unique representation?

Comment: $1/3$ and $2/3$ are both in $C$.

Comment: I didn't get what you want to say. Please explain it.

Comment: For Question 1, take $a=1/3$. Then both $a$ and $a+a$ are in $C$.

Comment: OK Thanks for pointing out it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Question 1: No. The Cantor set is constructed by taking $[0,1]$ splitting it in three equal parts and leaving out the middle part of these three. This is than repeated for the parts left behind (thus dividing these in three again and throwing the middle portion away). The first separation leaves us with $[0, \frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{2}{3},1]$. If we now take $a=\frac{1}{3}$ we see immediately that $a+a=\frac{2}{3}$ is in the Cantor set, yet $a\neq 0$.

Question 2: By using Question 1 we can immediately show that not all elements of the Cantor set are unique, as you have done. If you can prove that every element of $[0,2]$ can be writte as an addition of two elements of the Cantor set we can construct other elements of $[0,2]$ with these combinations.